# Need Laravel Route::controller and Route::controllers

Tags: laravel

As we know in Laravel 5.2 `Route::controller()` and `Route::controllers()` method was deprecated but it was very handy for reducing the number of routes. I was able to write simple route like this `Route::controller('admin/invoice','InvoiceController')`. With this simple one route, I can manage all things related to making invoice related work by a controller.

```
class InvoiceController extends Controller{
   public function getInvoices(){ }
   public function getInvoiceDetails(){ }
   public function postStoreInvoice(){ }
   public function postUpdateInvoice(){ }
   public function postStoreInvoiceDetails(){ }
   public function postupdateInvoiceDetails(){ }

   public function postDeleteInvoice(){ }
   public function postDeleteInvoiceDetails(){ }

   ....
}
```

but unfortunately this `Route::controller()` and `Route::controllers()` no longer available laravel version > 5.1. An option available `Route::resource()` but it has a limited number of the route. The laravel route is Macroable, there is an option to extend the route features like

```
Illuminate\Routing\Router::macro('controller', function ($routes) {
    // implementation
});
```

Is there anyone who implements `Route::controller()` and `Route::controllers()` method for Laravel 5.8, 6 ? or suggest any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Route::resource()` or `Route::resources()`.

**Example:**

```
Route::resource('books', 'BookController');
```

this will assumes you have

```
class BookController extends Controller {
    // to list resources.
    public function index();

    // to show create form. 
    public function create(); 

    // to store resource in database. 
    public function store(); 

    // to show single resource. 
    public function show(); 

    // to show edit form. 
    public function edit(); 

    // to edit and then store the modified resource in database. 
    public function update();

    // to delete a resource from database. 
    public function destroy(); 
}
```

You should read https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers for more information.

## Edit

Implicit controllers was removed in version `5.2` for some reason.

> If you come from the CodeIgniter world, then you may have warm and fuzzy 
>   feelings for implicit routing. You know, where the URI matches up to
>   the controller method that will be called. You might even want this
>   for your Laravel development (which Laravel can do).
>
> Though it might seem useful at first to simply call
>   Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController') and then declare all of
>   your desired routes from the controller, there are a number of
>   setbacks to this. Think about how you would, when using implicit routing,
>   leverage named routes, or create nested resources, or even do
>   something as simple as rename your controller class without affecting
>   your URI design.
>
> No, when it comes to implicit routing, just say no.

**source**: https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-no-to-implicit-routing

However if you want this functionality you can use this package:
[Laravel Routes Publisher](https://github.com/themsaid/laravel-routes-publisher) or [Laravel Advanced Route](https://github.com/lesichkovm/laravel-advanced-route)

Comment: I know that and I have mentioned it on my post. 
`An option available Route::resource() but it has a limited number of the route.`

Comment: In controller, controllers methods does it any security issue?

Comment: No, It was dropped in favour of design. It kind of makes it hard when it comes to rename your controller or leverage named routes etc.